# Restricting characters entered in textbox using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I need to validate a textbox that it should allow only certain characters and after the limit is reached the textbox should not allow entering characters in it.It can be done by Javascript but dont know how to do.. Anyone please help..

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery

Comment: What sort of validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I have provided a 2 solutions:
1)js function 'TextLimit':which keeps a check on count of characters typed into the textbox.
2)maxlength attribute: specifies the maximum length (in characters) of an input field.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Test</TITLE>
<script>
function TextLimit(){
    var text = document.getElementById('myinput');
   if (text.value.length > 10){
        alert('You exceeded the limit');
        text.value = text.value.substring(0,10);
    }
}  
</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<input name="myinput" type="text" value='' id="myinput" onkeyup="TextLimit()">
<br>
//this is using the maxlength attribute of textbox
<input type="text" name="inputtext" maxlength="10">
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1):

Single Line textboxes automatically follow the maxLength attribute.

[Dynamicdrive.com](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex16/maxlength.htm) has a javascript script that enforces max length on multiline by truncating the text entered to max length.

One way to add the required attributes to every control is by overiding the render method of the control.

You can also do it with a RegularExpressionValidator:

```
RegularExpressionValidator regexValidator = new RegularExpressionValidator();
if (this.MaxLength > 0)
{
    regexValidator.ValidationExpression = ".{0," + <textbox>.MaxLength + "}";
 }
 else
 {
     regexValidator.ValidationExpression = ".*";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [jQuery - numeric](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/) with [maxLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534157(VS.85).aspx) (if you're ok with it being ignored on certain versions of firefox).

Comment: How to do without using jQuery